# Journey builder wait activity delay

Tags: journeybuilder, wait-element

In my journey, there is a wait by attribute. The wait interval is on ReviewDate (GMT Standard Time). But it leaves wait activity sometimes the next day, sometimes 2 days later, sometimes 5 days later. I have examples with all 3 cases. It is quite random. How can it be fixed and sent as per the defined wait activity i.e. on the date of the attribute?

Comment: This is happening in an old version of the journey which is still running.

Comment: From the Salesforce support: Further on this, the contact data in the back end is not updating. How can I update it manually and then automate it to update regularly?